# APN does not deliver some of my notifications

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

I have two application servers connecting to the production Apple Push Gateway (gateway.push.apple.com), both sending notifications to the same application, using the same push certificate. I am using javapns to send notifications to APN.

Notifications originating from one of the servers are (almost) consistently ignored by APN: logs show that the notifications ARE sent to the correct PushIDs, but only one of my 3 test devices is able to actually show the notification. In the same time, when notification is sent from my other application server, the notification is visualized by all the three devices almost instantly. The application server which gets ignored by the APN is running Debian, the one which is not getting ignored is running Windows.

Up to now I have verified that:
* Both application servers (AS) are running the same sending code, with same settings.
* Both AS are using the same push certificate.
* both AS are sending to the same device tokens.
* Both AS are actually sending, in the sense there is no exception writing in the stream of the socket connecting me the the APN service.
* Both AS are using the same push gateway (gateway.push.apple.com:2195)
* Both AS are not connected for too long to the push gateway (at most 10 seconds after the last message). Because of the load, both of them are not connecting too frequently too.
* All the test devices are running the same push enabled application.
* Both of the servers has installed the new Entrust 2048 bit certificate, which Apple announced would be used effective 22 Dec 2010. On the ignored server I did ls on the certificates directory to verify. On the other - I checked in the Windows Internet properties.
* The ignored server is in server farm, running without continuously last 2 months. The not-ignored server is on my development machine, started and stopped frequently.
* Both servers used to be working fine and their notifications - respected by APN until 25th or 26th of December.

Answer (score 0):

JavaPNS was recently updated to 2.0, and fixed ALL reported issues up to the release date. The library has received significant reliability and error handling improvements during the past few weeks.  If you are still experiencing issues with JavaPNS, I would suggest you try with version 2.0 on http://code.google.com/p/javapns/.